# how can i put variables inside ndarray

Tags: python, sympy, numpy-ndarray

```
from sympy import symbols

a = symbols('a')

b = symbols('b')

F = 2*a+3*b

A=np.array([[F, 0],[0, F]])*2

print(A)
```

Prints:

```
----------------------------------
[[4*a + 6*b 0]
 [0 4*a + 6*b]]
----------------------------------
```

From here I want to put `a=1 b=2` for example, and get `A`
how can I put those values inside?

[[16 0]
[0 16]]

Comment: I am sorry, your question is not very clear to me. What does `symbols('a')` do and what do you mean by setting `a=1` and `b=2` and get `A`?

Comment: I used [from sympy import symbols] to make 'a' and 'b' as symbol(variable).
Then I made ndarray 'A' which contains those variables. Now I want to put specific value of variable inside 'A'.
For example, if i put a=1, b=2 then A will be [[16 0],[0 16]]

Comment: @Rafael `symbols('a')` defines `a` as a sympy variable, which allows you to do symbolic mathematics with it. I believe that OP wishes to then perform a variable substitution to determine the value of their matrix `A` given the values of `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 2):

Numpy doesn't have interoperability with Sympy, meaning that performing these substitutions will almost definitely not work. Instead, you may want to use [Sympy matrices](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/matrices.html), which will allow you to perform the substitutions.

```py
from sympy import symbols, Matrix

a, b = symbols('a, b')

F = 2 * a + 3 * b

A = Matrix([
    [F, 0],
    [0, F]
]) * 2

A = A.subs([(a, 1), (b, 2)])

print(A)
# Matrix([[16, 0], [0, 16]])
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as the answer if it answered your question!